# In Laravel, why a "show" route ruins a "create" route?

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 routes:

```
Route::get('/topics/{topic}', 'TopicsController@show')->name('topics.show');
Route::get('/topics/create', 'TopicsController@create')->name('topics.create');
```

If I do not comment out the first one, the 2nd one will return `404 not found`.
But if I do comment out the first one, the 2nd one will work correctly.

In other words, the first route ruins the 2nd one.

The button that direct to the 2nd route is:

```
<a href="{{ route('topics.create') }}" class="btn btn-success float-right">
     <i class="fas fa-edit mr-1"></i>
     Create a new topic
</a>
```

Could anyone give me a little hint about why is that?

Thanks!

Comment: just like `$var = $_GET['hello']; $var = 'go away';` will be ruined too ! what if the "variable" topic has the "create" value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just like

```
$var = $_GET['hello'];
$var = 'go away';
```

will be ruined too ! what if the "variable" topic has the "create" value?

to solve this you will need to re-order your routes to preserve the `topic` keyword

```
Route::get('/topics/create', 'TopicsController@create')->name('topics.create');
Route::get('/topics/{topic}', 'TopicsController@show')->name('topics.show');
```

or by adding some regex for your first route to make sure that the `$topic` value is not `create`

```
Route::get('/topics/{topic}', 'TopicsController@show')->name('topics.show')->where('topic', '^((?!topic).)*$');
```

Comment: Oh... You are right. Thanks. I am new to Laravel, didn't know the order of routes matters.. I will accept your answer in 8 mins!

Comment: @powerseed I see, I also updated the answer to include an alternative way

Comment: @hassan In your alternative way, The regex values is wrong.. not `'^((?!topic).)*$'`. but `'^((?!create).)*$'`

Answer (score 0):

Just to extend on the answer already given, which is perfect. If you use Resource Controllers and the `resource` method on the `Route` Facade you can see an example of this route ordering handled for you by the framework.

1. `php artisan make:controller --resource TopicsController`
2. Add `Route::resource('topics', 'TopicsController');` to your `web.php`
3. Run `php artisan route:list | grep topics`

```sh
+--------+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Domain | Method                                 | URI                                                            | Name                             | Action                                                                           | Middleware                                                              |
+--------+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|        | GET|HEAD                               | topics                                                         | topics.index                     | App\Http\Controllers\TopicsController@index                                      | web                                                                     |
|        | POST                                   | topics                                                         | topics.store                     | App\Http\Controllers\TopicsController@store                                      | web                                                                     |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | topics/create                                                  | topics.create                    | App\Http\Controllers\TopicsController@create                                     | web                                                                     |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | topics/{topic}                                                 | topics.show                      | App\Http\Controllers\TopicsController@show                                       | web                                                                     |
|        | PUT|PATCH                              | topics/{topic}                                                 | topics.update                    | App\Http\Controllers\TopicsController@update                                     | web                                                                     |
|        | DELETE                                 | topics/{topic}                                                 | topics.destroy                   | App\Http\Controllers\TopicsController@destroy                                    | web                                                                     |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | topics/{topic}/edit                                            | topics.edit                      | App\Http\Controllers\TopicsController@edit                                       | web                                                                     |
```

With Resources, Laravel handles wiring all the necessary routes for you and you'll see that `topics/create` is registered before any of the `topics/{topic}` routes for exactly the reason explained in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm explaining a way to write this routes in a single line. which looks very simple and clear.

```
Route::resource('topics', 'TopicsController')->only([
    'create', 'show'
]);
```